# Node.js spawn `docker run` command with extra streams

Tags: node.js, docker, pipe, child-process

I'm running a command line app from a Node.js process using `spawn()`.  The process is launched with extra pipes in the stdio option. Here's a simplified code sample:

```js
const stdio = ['ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'];
const process = spawn('/path/to/command', [], { stdio });

// Later...
const { 3: pipeWrite, 4: pipeRead } = process.stdio;
pipeRead.on('data', (data) => {
  if (String(data) === "PING?") {
    pipeWrite.write("PONG!");
  }
});
```

Now, this works fine but I want to run the command inside a docker container, using `docker run` as the spawned executable:

```js
const stdio = ['ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'];
const process = spawn(
  '/usr/bin/env', [
    'docker',
    'run',
    '--rm',
    'my-image',
    '/path/to/command'
  ], { stdio }
);
```

This fails, the command line app inside the docker container says it cannot write to pipe. Is it possible to achieve this with `docker run`?

I've set up a [Github repo](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/node-docker-spawn) that demonstrates the problem, though I should make it clear that this is merely a demonstration and I do not have the means to change behaviour of the real child process ([which is Chromium](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/docketeer/issues/5), in case anyone is interested!).

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to run a docker container from within another docker container? So the parent container has docker installed?

Comment: Why can't you use stdout and stdin in your ponger program?

Comment: @TheFool because I don't own it or control the source code. The Github repo where the ponger program exists is just a demonstration.

Comment: @MichaelBeeson no, I'm not running one container from within another. I'm running a container from a host operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you are trying isn't achievable. A child process can share the file descriptors with parent however when running a process inside docker it is containerized first. You can achieve this using named pipes instead of pipes. Named pipes are like pipes but have the interface of a file.

According to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/737754/is-it-possible-to-expose-pipe-file-from-docker-container) it is doable using named pipes:

This is the modified code of the Github repo you posted:

*test.js*

```js
import { spawn } from "child_process";
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import {describe, jest} from '@jest/globals'
import fs from "fs";

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

describe("on docker container", () => {
  let child;
  jest.setTimeout(60000);
  afterEach(() => child?.kill('SIGINT'));
  it("responds with PONG! when PING? is sent", async () => {
    child = spawn(
      "/usr/bin/env",
      [
        "docker",
        "run",
        "--rm",
        "--init",
        `-v=${ __dirname }:/usr/app`,
        "node:latest",
        "node",
        "/usr/app/ponger.js"
      ],
      {
        stdio: ['inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit']
      }
    );

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fifoWritePath = path.resolve(`${ __dirname }/named_pipe_in`);
      const fifoReadPath = path.resolve(`${ __dirname }/named_pipe_out`);
      const pipeWrite = fs.createWriteStream(fifoWritePath);
      const pipeRead = fs.createReadStream(fifoReadPath);

      pipeRead.on('data', (message) => {
        console.log(message)
        if (String(message) === "PONG!\n") {
          resolve();
        }
        else {
          reject();
        }
      });
      pipeWrite.write("PING?\n");
    });
  });
});
```

*ponger.js*

```js
import fs from "fs";
import path from 'path';

const fifoReadPath = path.resolve('/usr/app/named_pipe_in');
const fifoWritePath = path.resolve('/usr/app/named_pipe_out');

const pipeRead = fs.createReadStream(fifoReadPath);
const pipeWrite = fs.createWriteStream(fifoWritePath);

pipeRead.on("data", (message) => {
  if (String(message) === "PING?\n") {
    pipeWrite.write("PONG!\n");
  }
});
```

Before you run `npm test` while in the directory of the project execute the following :

```
mkfifo --mode=777 named_pipe_out
mkfifo --mode=777 named_pipe_out
```

The previledges  are only for test purposes, keep in mind that such a setting can ruin the security of your application.

PS. I can elaborate further on *why* your approach will not going to work in this setting.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the effort. However, I actually have no control over the source of the spawned process, so I can't switch to named pipes unfortunately.

Comment: Okay, so you can't modify the `ponger.js` code? I also encourage you to make it clear in the question.

Comment: Correct. The Github repo was merely a demonstration of the specific extra pipes problem. I've clarified this in the question.

Comment: FYI your named pipe approach gave me an idea that I hoped would work but, apparently, FIFOs do not work on Docker for Mac. Neither do unix sockets, which is what I was trying out. https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/483

Comment: Can you describe your idea?

Comment: My plan was to use Node's `net.createServer()` to create two sockets instead, `-v` map them into the container on `docker run` and then use `sh -c` to exec the command inside with `>3 outputStream.sock <4 inputStream.sock` tacked on the end.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED: It seems docker ignores extraneous pipes, and the approach above does not work. What you could do instead, is create a shared volume, in which a stream/pipe is generated, and use it like you would want to.

Be aware that it is generally advised to avoid piping large amounts of data in/out of docker, as this results in quite heavy log files. (Among other issues)

Consider using a TCP socket from the host into the container instead

Comment: Interesting, I must have missed that note in the documentation. I'll see if I can get it working this way. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately switching to streams didn't work, I got the same error message. I've set up a [Github repo](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/node-docker-spawn) to demonstrate the problem with a Node app.

Comment: Updated answer. It seems this sadly is not possible.

Comment: Bounty awarded for being the first to answer, thanks again. I already suspected that it wasn't possible but just wanted to try and get confirmation here. Presumably, I could write a script that forwards data from a named pipe inside the container, but this isn't really ideal for my situation. I've added [a feature request](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/3677) at the Docker CLI Github repo, hopefully it will be possible some time in the future.